# How to extract array from JSON String in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

```
Hi, I'm working on a table looks like below:
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|     user_id    |                       j_games_information                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   hsbdgcy76s   |{"data": [{"game_id": "acb", "rewards":[{"no":3,"items":"oils"}]},{"game_id": "bsm", "rewards":[{"no":4,"items":"bombs"}]}]}    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   kslcn6vg76   |{"data": [{"game_id": "ohf", "rewards":[{"no":6,"items":"oils"}]},{"game_id": "dfg", "rewards":[{"no":7,"items":"bombs"}]}]}   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My expected output will be:

```
-----------------------------------
|     user_id    |     game_ids   |                                             
-----------------------------------
|   hsbdgcy76s   |      acb       |   
-----------------------------------
|   hsbdgcy76s   |      bsm       |   
-----------------------------------
|   kslcn6vg76   |      ohf       |   
-----------------------------------
|   kslcn6vg76   |      dfg       |   
-----------------------------------
```

I tried the following code but this query returned no results. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

```
select user_id, JSON_EXRACT_SCALAR(json_array,"$.game_id") AS game_ids
from table, unnest(json_extract_array(j_games_information,"$.data")) AS json_array
```

But

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `json_file` with `j_games_information`

```
with mytable as (
    select 'hsbdgcy76s' as user_id, '{"data": [{"game_id": "acb", "rewards":[{"no":3,"items":"oils"}]},{"game_id": "bsm", "rewards":[{"no":4,"items":"bombs"}]}]}' as j_games_information union all 
    select 'kslcn6vg76' as user_id, '{"data": [{"game_id": "ohf", "rewards":[{"no":6,"items":"oils"}]},{"game_id": "dfg", "rewards":[{"no":7,"items":"bombs"}]}]}' as j_games_information
)
select user_id, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(json_array,"$.game_id") AS game_ids
from mytable, unnest(json_extract_array(j_games_information,"$.data")) AS json_array
```

[image]

Comment: Ops, I actually used the j_games_information.

Comment: Well, you query worked for me then